# react native: how to change style of active segment?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using `react-native`, I want to change the style of active segment button, I have this code:

```
import { Segment } from "native-base";

<Segment style={{backgroundColor: '#222'}}>
      <Button bending style={{width: '50%', height: '100%',borderColor: '#222'}}>
        <Text>Bending</Text>
      </Button>
      <Button history style={{width: '50%', height: '100%',borderColor: '#222'}}>
        <Text>History</Text>
      </Button>
    </Segment>
```

when any button sellected, I want it has the style:

```
borderBottomColor: 'red'
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Create one state to manage selected button and update on clicked then use style like this

```
<Button bending
  style={(this.state.selectedButton == "bending") // condition to add dynamic selector
    ? styles.selectedButtonStyle // with red color
    : buttonStyle} // normal style
>
```

Comment: can you write the syntax with example please, because I'm a begginner